# Moshi can't convert Json when Date item is null

Tags: android, date, moshi, data-class

I'm using Moshi in my application and for my `Date` that I will get from the server, I just defined a custom adapter for Moshi, but thing that will happen is that when my date is null, `Moshi` can't to convert the `JSON` to my model, So it gives me an error like below:

This is my data class:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class BoughtSmart(
        var id: Int?,
        var title: String?,
        @Json(name = "start_date") var startDate: Date?,
        @Json(name = "expire_date") var expireDate: Date?,
        @Json(name = "created_time") var createdTime: Date?,
        @Json(name = "modified_time") var modifiedTime: Date?
)
```

My Moshi Custome Adapter:

```
class CustomDateAdapter : JsonAdapter<Date>() {

    private val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(SERVER_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH)
    private val TAG = CustomDateAdapter::class.java.simpleName
    @FromJson
    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader?): Date? {

        var dateAsString = ""

        reader?.apply {
            try {
                dateAsString = nextString()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error [${e}]")
            }
        }

        return dateFormat.parse(dateAsString)
    }

    @ToJson
    override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: Date?) {
        if (value != null) {
            writer.value(value.toString())
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val SERVER_FORMAT = ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    }
}
```

Error form Moshi:

```
com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected a string but was NULL at path $.results[0].expire_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        reader?.apply {
            try {
               if (peek() == JsonToken.STRING) {
                dateAsString = nextString()
               } else {
                 nextNull()
               }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error [${e}]")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can handle it easily by checking JsonReader.Token:

```
@FromJson
override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader?): Date? {
  return try {

    val dateAsString = if (reader?.peek() == JsonReader.Token.NULL) 
    reader?.nextNull() else reader?.nextString()

    synchronized(dateFormat) {
        dateFormat.parse(dateAsString)
    }
  } catch (e: Exception) {
      e.printStackTrace()
      null
  }
}
```